# app crash when accessing First name from address book due to memory management

Tags: iphone, memory-management, cfstring

I am trying to access all the first name value field from the address book. I am using this code for this

```
CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(aSource, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
first_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
CFRealease(firstname)
```

I am not using ARC. So i need to CFRealease(firstname) at the end. But in my code when i add CFRealease(firstname) my app crashes at this point and without this the app works fine.

But when i try to analyse my app by using analyzer it says **object Leaked: object allocated and stored into 'firstname' is not refrenced later in the execution path and has a retain count of +1.**

Case is same for midname and last name whose code are given below.

```
 CFStringRef midname = ABRecordCopyValue(aSource, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty);
 mid_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",midname];
 CFRelease(midname);

 CFStringRef lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(aSource, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
 last_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
 CFRelease(lastName);
```

Please tell where i am doing it wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the app crashes because your first_name string is storing some string and after storing your immediately realising it. And you must be using  first_name in your application as well,so once you have realsed the first_name and it doesn't getting any allocation in memory pool.
So, try realising your string where you doesn't require them anymore.

Comment: You should check the writing of your variables (upper and lower case), e.g. you are using firstName and firstname.

Comment: @DeepakKhiwani Thanks for your reply but i am releasing firstName after i have sent the firstName value to another NSString variable first_name and then i released firstName because now i don't need it anymore and somehow i have also tried it to release even at the end of my for loop where i don't need it any more but that doesn't work too.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner thats a typo mistake here. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you store a reference to the first name in `firstname` (not `firstName`), your app will crash when you try to release the object referenced if `firstname` is `nil`. This can happen if your app doesn't have access to the address book (the contacts data base), because the user has not yet granted access to it. This must be done stating with iOS 6. In this case, no contacts are returned.
You could ask for access e.g. using the following code:

```
-(bool)userGrantedReadAccessToContacts
{
    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(contactsRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
    else { // iOS 5 or earlier
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    return accessGranted;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am already handling this permissions issue and as i told you the problem is regarding the memory management. Anyway Thanks for your reply.

Comment: So you are sure that firstname is not nil when you are trying to release it?

Comment: Yes i am sure. It was a memory leak issue. I solved it by not using the cfstring. I mean now i am not using   ** CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(aSource, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
first_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];** I am directly using the **first_name = ABRecordCopyValue(aSource, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);** and it worked without a leak

Comment: Well, originally you said "when i add CFRealease(firstname) my app crashes at this point". Thus I assumed that the release was the problem. You ADDITIONALLY said you had the error message "object allocated and stored into 'firstname' is not refrenced later", but it WAS referenced later in the release, at least if firstName and firstname are the same. Now it looks to me that first_name is also the same as firstName and firstname - VERY confusing... At least you solved your problem.